# Nearby Connections disconnects when sending (larger) file payloads

Tags: android, google-nearby

I'm developing an offline photo transfer app using Nearby Connections 2.0. Advertising, discovery, sending byte payloads, Google sample apps(RockPaperScissors and WalkieTalkie) all work fine but I have 2 issues.

First and most importantly, after successful connection initation between devices, I send a byte payload to give 'take picture' command from advertiser device, the discoverer receives the payload and takes a photo, then sends that photo to the advertiser as a file payload. The problem occurs here, as the devices often disconnect when the discoverer sends the file payload, before even the advertiser's onPayloadReceived method is called. I tried reducing the size of the photos, to as low as 30kB's, that rarely solves the problem. When I switch devices, making the old advertiser the new discoverer and the old discoverer the new advertiser, the problem doesn't occur often, even without reducing the size of the payload (payloads around 30kb almost never give me this issue with devices being switched). The only log I get from Nearby is this:

[image: Nearby log screenshot].

First line is logged when the connection initiates, second line is logged when the devices disconnect.

Secondly, the discovery and connection initation sometimes take up to minutes, but rarely exceed 30 seconds.When they do, I get this error on log:

[image: The error on log screenshot.]

Both devices run on Android 6.0.1, and are on the same network. I use star strategy. The problematic device is Lenovo P1A41, other device is Lg X-screen(K500).

Answer (score 0):

Could you try and run [our sample apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby/tree/master/connections) on these devices to see whether they work as expected? We regularly transfer 10s of MB of data on Nearby Connections, so I'd like to rule out any hardware issues on the phones you're using.

BTW, which phones are you using (and which one of these is the more problematic of the 2)?

P.S. Being on the same network isn't need in Nearby Connections -- we're completely offline and P2P.

Comment: First, the WiFi connection failing to be established just means that you won't get higher bandwidth, but the Bluetooth connection should still be established, and should be able to send your FILE Payload (albeit at slower speeds) without entailing a long connection-establishment delay (the WiFi upgrades happen in the background, in a non-blocking fashion) -- is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Also, if you're able to sustain a session with WalkieTalkie (which uses STREAM Payloads) of more than a minute or 2, with data being sent across both sides, that's a hint that you might have a race condition in your code that's leading to the disconnection.

Comment: Could you maybe try using P2P_CLUSTER as the Strategy and see if the disconnection problem still occurs?

Comment: As for your first comment, i couldn't understand what you are asking. I didn't test the speed but i can test it if it is of help. I'm able to sustain a walkietalkie session longer than a minute. I couldn't get cluster strategy to connect between devices(I couldn't solve why it doesn't connect although I've tried with 2 other devices, total of 4), however I tried the app on 4 different phones (2 pairs ) then the ones I mentioned in my question, the problem still occurs.

Comment: The WiFi comment was about your second problem (about a delay in establishing the connection) -- let's table that discussion for now.

CLUSTER and STAR use the exact same connection methodology (BT Classic and BLE), so I can't explain why one works and the other doesn't, sorry.